# Require files from gem in Ruby script without bundle exec

Tags: ruby, bundler

I have a script that needs to require specific files out of gems defined in the project Gemfile.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'some_gem/helpers/some_helper'

... rest of script
```

When I run the script, I get an error about not being able to load `some_helper.rb`.  If I run with `bundle exec command...` then everything works.
I understand that bundle exec exposes the Gems to the $LOAD_PATH which lets `require` work.  Is there a way to move that capability into the script so users don't have to type `bundle exec`?

Do I just need to add `require "bundler/setup"` to the script before I require the gem files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://bundler.io/v1.12/#getting-started

:)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'rubygems' # because reasons.. most probably it is not needed unless you are using really old ruby where it is not loaded by default
                   # also at the moment rubygems and bundler are being merged :) 
require 'bundler/setup' # for things installed with bundler
require 'some_gem/helpers/some_helper'
```

You can also check e.g. http://mislav.net/2013/01/understanding-binstubs/